# Set Default Value for Node Title

Tags: nodes

I have a content type named `Account`, and it has a field named `account_number`. Since I import the data from a csv file using feeds. The Node title for each account is always empty.

Is there a way to set the node title default to its `account_number`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used this personally, but the [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module is designed to handle tasks like this.  If you have [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) installed and enabled, you should be able to populate the autotitle using a field value.

Answer (score 1):

On Drupal 8, you can use [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) module.